# loading model contents into a navbar dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

the standard code for a navbar drop down is like this

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          </ul>
```

how do I go about filling the `dropdown-menu` with contents of a db model? I've recently done this for a dropdown field of a Rails form for the same model like this `<%= fea.select(:artist_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Artist.all, "id", "name")) %>`. what's the solution with the Bootstrap navbar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to fetch the records and show them in `li` one by one.

action_controller.rb

```
before_action :set_artists

private
  def set_artists
    @artists = Artist.all
  end
```

View

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  Dropdown<span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <% @artists.each do |artist| %>
    <li><%= link_to artist.name, artist %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: oh wow, that simple! only thing, which controller should I put that into? the navbar is shared among all the views.

Comment: In that case put it in the `application_controller`. It will be executed before all other controller actions.